# Delete Gmail emails programmatically

Tags: android, email, gmail

I am working on an application in which I am accessing Gmail emails in my own application, but I am unable to delete those emails through their id. How can I do this?

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse((new StringBuilder()).append(
                "content://gmail-ls/messages/").append(account_name).append("/").append(mail_id).toString());
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(cont, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // getContentResolver().delete(
            // Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/"
            // + account_name + "/" + mail_id + ""), null,
            // null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: The problem is that , I am able to access gmail programmatically in my application but i am unable to delete them using the code given above.This code is taken from gmail.java's delete method.please give me a solution which will be able to delete gmails in our own application .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from whatever your problem seems to be (you did not specify it, but it sounds like you can read the mails?), you cannot really rely on this feature.

The last version for which this works is 2.3.4.1 
See: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/reading-and-receiving-messages/XD0C4sw9K7U

> In the near future, we are going to make a change which may affect
>   your apps.  Historically, the Gmail app has exposed an undocumented
>   Content Provider, protected by a non-public Permission value, that
>   allows apps granted permission by the user to read users' email and
>   also execute live queries.  We have determined, as part of our
>   continuous effort to improve the level of security of Gmail, that this
>   API does not meet modern security standards.  Therefore, we will be
>   disabling it in the next update to Gmail on Android devices running
>   Froyo and later releases.

And secondly, I don't think this method was more then just `read` permission.

Comment: Yes and no. You need to do the OAuth dance, and then access the inbox with IMAP (you need to turn that on too) or POP. Not very easy, but doable

Comment: sidenote: for reading, there is the gmail atom feed which is easier to implement (you don't need any imap/pop mail code), but that is just a feed of unread mail, not very usefull for deleting

Comment: ive used content uri in my application , which is more useful than atom feed cause i m getting all the mail read,unread and i can sort them by applying constraints.But no facilities to delete,not even in gmail atom feed.

Comment: Like I said, the content uri was an undocumented 'feature' which is removed, so your app will only work until 2.2 . I understand why you used it, but that doesn't really matter that much. And the feed obviously doesn't have any delete functions... its a feed. Your only options is IMAP. Not a fun answer, but the truth...