# Delete Recently Sent email Javamail

Tags: android, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am sending email through JavaMail service , in android app , is there any way to delete the sent email automatically from sender `sent Items` using javamail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464706/delete-email-on-server-using-javax-mail

Comment: @PavneetSingh that is for java desktop , but how can android achieve such task ?

Comment: seems like it's gonna be hard due to security reasons , hit this link to know more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788155/delete-gmail-emails-programmatically

Comment: The first link above shows how to delete a message.  There's nothing "desktop" about that solution; it will work in Android as well.  But note that this doesn't do it "automatically".  You have to program it to open the mail folder containing the sent messages, find the message you want to delete, mark it as deleted, and then expunge the deleted messages in the folder.